# Notification of AMQP broker disconnect/reconnect with Spring-AMQP/RabbitMQ

Tags: spring, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

One of the nice features of Spring-AMQP is that it appears to implement the required logic to reconnect Spring application to the message broker when the broker goes down and comes back up.

What I'm looking for is the preferred method of detecting when such disconnect/reconnect events occur within the application.

The best I've come up with so far is a polling-like mechanism where I attempt to acquire a channel from the connection factory at a regular interval.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feel free to open an 'Improvement' [JIRA Issue](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/AMQP) - we could emit an `ApplicationEvent` when the connection is lost (and re-established); you could then subscribe to that event with an `ApplicationListener`.

In the meantime, you could do something via your logging subsystem - for example, with Log4J, you can create a custom appender to get logs with the `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` category, such as...

```
16:05:50.042 WARN  [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-6][org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer] Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: connection error; reason: {#method<connection.close>(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - broker forced connection closure with reason 'shutdown', class-id=0, method-id=0), null, ""}

16:05:55.048 WARN  [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-7][org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer] Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it. Exception summary: org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
```

EDIT:

There is also a `ConnectionListener` interface which you can register an implementation of with the connection factory; you can learn of new connections with it, but `onClose()` is currently only called when the connection is explicitly closed by destroying the factory.

However, the `onCreate()` gives you a handle to the connection so you could call its `isOpen()` method from time to time, but don't do that in the `onCreate()` method itself - save off the connection. You must exit the `onCreate()` for all to work as planned.

Comment: Added a note about the ConnectionListener interface.

Comment: Thanks Gary - I've filed a JIRA improvement issue for this.  I do have a question regarding your suggestion WRT the ConnectionListener.  Would a connection handle acquired in onCreate() as you describe survive rabbit going down and coming back up? (e.g. isOpen() returns true until the broker goes down, false while the broker is down, then true when the connection factory reestablishes connectivity)

Comment: Once the connection is closed, that particular instance will never return `true` from `isOpen()`. However, when the new connection is established, your `ConnectionListener` will be again called, but this time with the new connection.